# Error with object array in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have initialized array of object and tried to set value from database via loop

```
$recentpost=array_fill(0,$no,new Post);

    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->order_by("id");
    $this->db->limit($no);

    $result=$this->db->get('posts');

    $rows=$result->num_rows();


    $i=0;
    foreach ($result->result() as $value) 
    {

        $recentpost[$i]->set($value->title,
                               $value->date,
                               $value->writer,
                               $value->views,
                               $value->id,
                               $value->post_id,
                               $value->comments,
                               $value->less
                            );

        $i++;
        if($i>=$no||$i>=$rows)
        break;
    }
    var_dump($recentpost);
```

the database is [database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uCbo.png)

but when dump $recentpost it contains only the last value of database in all index of the array I have no idea what's going on
[var dump image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCnmG.png)

sorry for bad english ,i want to thank in advance

Comment: `print_r($value)` inside `foreach` shows correct data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here `$recentpost=array_fill(0,$no,new Post);`. You fill array with single  object. Which means in your `foreach` loop you're just changing its state several times.

Example:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->prop = 'foo';
$array = array_fill(0, 2, $obj);
```

This is exactly what happens `var_dump($array)`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["prop"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["prop"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
}
```

We're using same object. So:

```
$array[0]->prop = 'bar';
echo $array[1]->prop; // Outputs: bar
```

---

Possible solution is to fill array in loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $no; $i++){
    $recentpost[$i] = new Post; 
}
```

So now it is filled with different object for each element of array

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: Beacuse array_fill third argument is used to fill array with single value. So the whole array filled with the same object.

Comment: And what is the solution then?

Comment: if you create the array in the loop then you cant use it outside then what is the use of it?

Comment: In PHP, you can